# Angularjs navigation items calling detail view

Tags: angularjs

I have my base.html:

```
<div ng-controller=NavCtrl>
        <nav>
             <a  ng-click="getWork(work)"  ng-repeat='work in works'>{{$index+1}}</a>
        </nav>
</div>
```

My routers:

```
.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/ardiye/:workNo', {
      controller:'DetailCtrl',
      templateUrl:'/static/web/js/api/templates/detail.html'
    });
})
```

And my contrrollers:

```
.controller('NavCtrl', function($scope, $location, $http) {
  $scope.works = [];
  $http({method: 'GET', url: '/api/v1/work'}). //collects all works
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.works = data.objects;
  });

  // Trying to pass the selected work to new view, how?
  $scope.getWork = function(work) { 
     $scope.selectedWork=work; 
     $location.path('/ardiye/'+work.id+'/') };

})

.controller('DetailCtrl', function($scope) {
 // here i have to get the selectedWork, how?

})
```

detail.html:

```
<h1>{{selectedWork.title}}</h1>
```

Nav controller sends a list of works.  Then when a link is clicked  i  want to send the work object to the new detail controller via router ( in order not to make another server call ).

But when the link is clicked 'getWork' function can not be called and i can not send the work object to the detail controller.  How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to share data between controllers is to do it with a service. In this particular case, this simple code should work:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/ardiye', {templateUrl: 'page1.html', controller: 'View1Ctrl'})
        .when('/ardiye/:id', {templateUrl: 'page2.html', controller: 'View2Ctrl'})
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/ardiye'})
}]);

app.factory('WorkService', [function(){
    var WorkService = {};
    WorkService.data = { SOMEIDFORITEM1: {id: "SOMEIDFORITEM1", content: "some content"}, SOMEIDFORITEM2: {id: "SOMEIDFORITEM2", content: "some content"}};
    WorkService.someMethod = function(){}; //in case you also need to share logic
    return WorkService;
}]);

app.controller('View1Ctrl'. ['$scope', 'WorkService', function($scope, WorkService){
    $scope.workService = WorkService;
    $scope.works = $scope.workService.data;
}]);

app.controller('View2Ctrl'. ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'WorkService', function($scope, $routeParams, WorkService){
    $scope.workService = WorkService;
    $scope.currentWork = $scope.workService.data[$routeParams.id];
}]);
```

Cheers

Comment: And what do you think about @Dayan $location.path answer is it another solution? I have tried but could not make $location.path work?

Comment: I have updated my question... Do you still think that i have to use service ?

Answer (score 0):

include $location service in your controller and once you have your work object just call

```
$location.path('ardiye/'+id);
```

you are trying to call the function before following the link and that won't work.

Comment: what did you do? can you post a peace of your code??